# Qt - GUI-based and threaded Multi client socket programming

Tags: multithreading, qt, sockets, user-interface

I am implementing below link with gui:

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Multithreaded_Client_Server.php

My code is as same as above link.

I know it is impossible to:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow , public QTcpServer
```

So I just created:

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "myserver.h"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(MyServer *ms, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();    

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and

```
//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(MyServer *ms, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ms->StartServer();
    connect(this,SIGNAL(SendCommand(QString)),ms,SLOT(GetCommand(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and modified

```
//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "myserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyServer *Server = new MyServer;

    MainWindow w(Server);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

As I said, I have a server and several clients handled by threads. I want to connect my GUI to the socket in MyThread somehow. 
All of I need is When I write some text in textbox and press button in mainwindow, it wrtites to socket and return the response to another textbox.

I have serached but I do not understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new signal, that will be emitted in `on_pushButton_clicked()` and will post your data from the **MainWindow** textfield to a specific thread, that will then write it in the socket? Recieving could be orginized in the same way.

If you create your `MyServer` object in your `MainWindow` class constructor, you can change your `MyServer` constructor, adding:

```
 MyServer(MainWindow* parent)
 {
      //Save parent somewhere inside the class
      my_parent = parent;
 }

void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
   // We have a new connection
   qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

   // Every new connection will be run in a newly created thread
   MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

   // connect signal/slot
   // once a thread is not needed, it will be beleted later
   connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

   thread->start();

   QObject::connect(my_parent, &MainWindow::myNewSendigQStrigSignal, thread, &MyThreadClass::slotNewMsg);
}
```

And realization of `on_pushButton_clicked` looks something like that

```
 MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
     QString data = getDataFromTextField();
     emit myNewSendigQstrigSignal(data);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks dear Alex, I have an instance of MyThread class in MyServer class not in MainWindow, so I can not connect them. If you know I really appreciate you to give me an example in detail

Comment: Ok, one question please. Is it necessary to create `MyServer` object in the main function, or it is possible to move it to `MainWindow` class? Because moving it to `MainWindow` will simplify your constructor and also simplify a bit a way of solving your question, I think.

Comment: No Problem. It is better to move for me

Comment: If you move it is difficult to re-implement incomingConnection. take care.

Comment: Thanks but one problem: MyThreadClassObject is created in incomingConnection slot, and there is no MyThreadClassObject when constructor of MyThread is called

Comment: Yes, excuse me, The right one: ... and there is no MyThreadClassObject when constructor of MyServer is called

Comment: ummmmm, sorry for simple question, But now I have problem with constructor argument. I can not use MainWindow in argument of MyServer constructor. There is a circle between mainwindows.h and myserver.h. each of them include each other.

Comment: You can include `MainWindow.h`  directly in `MyServer.cpp` file, and in your `MyServer.h` file only "pre" declare it by writing `class MainWindow;`. It will be enough to decalre a constructor with pointer to MainWindow (`MainWindow*`). I think that will solve your trouble.